# Nested Redux Reducer returns null home state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I have nested reducer for todos. I am using "[reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)" library for nested objects. Below you can find ADD_TODO reducer and selector, but when i call ADD_TODO reducer; it makes state like this;

```
{
  0: null,
  1: null,
}
```

**Add Todo Reducer**

```
import { makeSelectTodos } from 'containers/HomePage/selectors';

const initialState = fromJS({
  todos: [],
  visibilityFilter: 'SHOW_ALL',
});

const todo = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function homeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        makeSelectTodos(),
        todo(undefined, action),
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Selector.js**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectHome = (state) => state.get('home');

const makeSelectTodos = () => createSelector(
  selectHome,
  (homeState) => homeState.get('todos')
);

export {
  selectHome,
  makeSelectTodos,
};
```

Comment: You are using immutablejs in your initial state (`fromJS`) but in your reducers returning plain JS (`return {...}`, `return[...]`) so you won't find `.get` methods on your state because after `ADD_TODO` action your state is no longer immutablejs.

Comment: Thank you. i am new to immutable with redux and yes forgot the fromJs. Now i can look for right solution. Returning immutable data for nested reducer.

Comment: offtop maybe: why do you use selectors in reducer? if you need to get some extra data to reduce you state you can pass it thru the action creators payload. there are you have access to store by calling getState() function:

````const someAction = params => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const someExtraData = someExtraDataSelector(getState());
  return dispatch({
    type: 'SOME_ACTION',
    payload: { ...params, ...someExtraData }
  });
}````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is at mapStateToProps because of not using immutable so i get different data structure. With using immutable "getIn" i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you want to return all todos in homeReducer with action type of 'ADD_TODO'. It's not quite right. Your component with todos list must think about this and it can get all todos via selectAllTodos selector.

You also didn't provide state to your `makeSelectTodos` function. As i can see your selector returns function, that returns createSelector function. There is mistake. You need to write something like this:

```
const selectHome = state => state.get('home');
const selectAllTodos = createSelector(
    selectHome,
    homeState => homeState.get('todos')
);
```

In action creators selectors can be used this way:

```
// action creators:

const addTodoAction = todo => ({
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    payload: todo
});

const addTodo = todo => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // here you able to use your selectors like:
    // const todos = selectAllTodos(getState());

    return dispatch(addTodoAction(todo));
};
```

Simplify your reducer logic as much as you can:

```
const todosReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_TODO') {
        return {
            id: action.payload.id,
            text: action.payload.text,
            completed: false
        };
    }

    return state;
};

const visibilityFilterReducer = (state = 'SHOW_ALL', action) => {
    // your visibility filter reducer logic
};

export default combineReducers({
    todos: todosReducer,
    visibilityFilter: visibilityFilterReducer
});
```

Good luck! :)